# Enabled click on play button of video tag even when there isn't "source" yet

Tags: html, angular

I have a secured videos that I want to generate a url source for them only for limited time , just after the user click on play button, the problem is the "play" button of the video won't be enabled if there isn't available source , and because of that I cant get a "click" event from him to generate the url for the video.
there is any option to force the video tag enable it play button even if there isn't source yet?

Comment: <video controls>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: If you will try it you will see that the play button still disabled

Comment: Then probably you need setup all video by yourself , please checkout this link: 
 http://iandevlin.github.io/mdn/video-player/